# Coupon code claim in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, journeybuilder, content-builder, sfmc-business-unit

I need to implement coupon claim process while sending email through campaign or journey ?

What is the solution to claim coupon code in email .

I have created a DE with 3 columns (CouponCode/IsClaimed/SubscriberKey) as mentioned in below link and loaded coupon codes into DE.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_offer_coupon_codes_via_ampscript.htm&type=5

I'm stuck in 2nd step on claiming coupon code in email . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already created the Data Extension you need to loop through the Data Extension.

1. Show fallback content if the IsClaimed Field has a 'True' value
2. Show the coupon code if the IsClaimed Field has a 'False' value.

   ```
    %%[ Set @CouponRow = ClaimRow("DE_NAME", "IsClaimed", "SubscriberID", 
    SubscriberID, "EmailAddress", Emailaddr) IF EMPTY(@CouponRow) THEN]%%
     <tr>No coupon code</tr>
    %%[ELSE ]%%  
    <!-- SHOW COUPON CODE --> <tr>%%= FIELD(@CouponRow,"CouponCode") =%%</tr>
    %%[ENDIF]%%
   ```

Comment: Thanks Jordan, 

I tried the solution provided in ampscript guide and it worked.

https://ampscript.guide/raiseerror/


The challenge I am facing now is, Couponcodes DE I have 2 coupon codes & my audience DE let's say I have 3 recipients, the email is being sent for 2 persons with coupon code and the error is not being thrown for the 3rd recipient. 

Where can I view the error message  "No coupons available". Will it be visible in UI? 

I checked for the status from Tracking Tab and it has been delivered to 2 recipients.

Comment: Hi Prasanna, in this case, when the audience DE is linked to the Couponcodes DE, the error message will be displayed in a UI. It's up to you how you want to display it using HTML. I would suggest running a test in Email Studio.